# Is using Puppeteer on Ubuntu will show the site that Ubuntu is used?

Tags: puppeteer, user-agent, headless

I was wondering if using Puppeteer + Extra stealth plugin on Ubuntu will allow the website to realize the OS of the browser is Ubuntu and not Windows?

I hope I can find my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Puppeteer will not show the host OS in the user agent. But it will have a headless chrome tag in the agent.

Although, you can update the user agent to say whatever you want. If you want, you can make it look like it's windows, ie browser...

Here is a good dev.to article covering this topic: https://dev.to/sonyarianto/user-agent-string-difference-in-puppeteer-headless-and-headful-4aoh